# How to connect Android Phone to Visual Studio in Xamarin

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

When I write an App with Xamarin with Visual Studio I can use an emulator.

But how can I simply connect my phone to Visual Studio so I can test the App into my Phone?

Comment: please read the docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/set-up-device-for-development

Comment: select the phone from the dropdown and click run - exactly like you do with the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

To use your Android phone as an emulator, you need to enable USB Debugging mode. Please note this only works on Android 8.1 and higher cellphone devices. To enable USB Debugging, follow these steps.

Step 1: Go to your phone Settings.

Step 2: Go to "About Phone" at the bottom.

Step 3: Go to "Software Information".

Step 4: Tap on "Build Number" continuously until it says  "Developer mode enabled".

Step 5: Go back to you phone Settings and you should find "Developer mode" below "About Phone"
.
Step 6: Enable "USB Debugging" and you should be good to go.